# Code I have written for Burger, Coca and Salad price calculation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, calculator, price

I have written a code to calculate Burger, Coca and Salad price. The code should return a number (or a factor) based on the number or each ordered item. I can't figure out which part of the code is not right. it doesn't work when I change the number of items.

```js
var BurgNum = document.getElementById('Bnum').value,

  CocNum = document.getElementById('Cnum').value,

  SalNum = document.getElementById('Snum').value,

  Totalprice;

function getValue(n) {
  return n >= 2 && n < 5 ? n * 0.9 : n == 0 ? 0 : n == 1 ? 1 : n - 1;
}
var XBurgNum = getValue(BurgNum);
var XCocNum = getValue(CocNum);
var XSalNum = getValue(SalNum);

Totalprice = XBurgNum * 10 + XCocNum * 5 + XSalNum * 4
document.getElementById('price').value = Totalprice;
```

```html
<html>
How many Burgers you want to order? <input type="number" id="Bnum" value="0" onchange="getValue(n);"></input>
<br> How many Cocas you want to order? <input type="number" id="Cnum" value="0" onchange="getValue(n);"></input>
<br> How many Salads you want to order? <input type="number" id="Snum" value="0" onchange="getValue(n);"></input>
<br> Price: <input type="number" id="price" readonly="readonly"></input>


</html>
```

Comment: BurgNum, CocNum, SalNum is set as value already. it is set as initialized value. so it won't be changed. you should get the element but value, then access the value when you need to calculate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a function `onchange` which returns a value, but does nothing with it.  Instead, your `onchange` function can get the values needed for the calculation and update the price accordingly.

```js
var burg = document.getElementById('Bnum'),
    coc = document.getElementById('Cnum'),
    sal = document.getElementById('Snum'),
    totalPrice = 0;

document.getElementById('price').value = totalPrice;

var updatePrice = function() {

    var burgNum = burg.value,
    cocNum = coc.value,
    salNum = sal.value;
    
    var xNums = [];
    
    [burgNum, cocNum, salNum].forEach(function(n, i) {
       xNums[i] = (n >= 2 && n < 5) ? n * 0.9 : n == 0 ? 0 : n == 1 ? 1 : n - 1;
    });
        
    totalPrice = xNums[0]*10 + xNums[1]*5 + xNums[2]*4;
        
    document.getElementById('price').value = totalPrice;
}
```

```html
How many Burgers do you want to order? 
<input type="number" id="Bnum" value ="0" onchange="updatePrice()"/><br>

How many Cocas do you want to order?
<input type="number" id="Cnum" value ="0" onchange="updatePrice()"/><br>

How many Salads do you want to order? 
<input type="number" id="Snum" value="0" onchange="updatePrice()"/><br>

Price:
<input type="number" id="price" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Comment: The code that you wrote does not have XBurgNum, XCocNum, XSalNum variables. (i.e if user types 2 for BurgNum the XBurgNum should be 1.8) which means if you choose 2 Burgers the price does not multiplied by 2 instead it multiplies by 1.8

Comment: I see what you are trying to do.  I updated the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not calling right statement on 'onchange' event. You just call the getVAlue(n) function which does nothing except return a value that you also use for

```
 var XBurgNum = getValue(BurgNum);
 var XCocNum = getValue(CocNum);
 var XSalNum = getValue(SalNum);
```

But you are not updating the output on change event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will help you...

```js
function getValue(val)
{
 var BurgNum = parseInt(document.getElementById('Bnum').value);
 var CocNum = parseInt(document.getElementById('Cnum').value);
 var SalNum = parseInt(document.getElementById('Snum').value);
 BurgNum = (BurgNum>=2 && BurgNum<5)?BurgNum*0.9:(BurgNum<2)?BurgNum:BurgNum-1;
 CocNum = (CocNum>=2 && CocNum<5)?CocNum*0.9:(CocNum<2)?CocNum:CocNum-1;
 SalNum = (SalNum>=2 && SalNum<5)?SalNum*0.9:(SalNum<2)?SalNum:SalNum-1;
 Totalprice = BurgNum*10 + CocNum*5 + SalNum*4;
 document.getElementById('price').value = (Totalprice>0 && Totalprice!=='NaN')?Totalprice:0;
}
```

```html
<html>
 How many Burgers you want to order? <input type="number" id="Bnum" value ="0" onChange="getValue(this.value);"></input>
    <br>
 How many Cocas you want to order? <input type="number" id="Cnum" value ="0" onChange="getValue(this.value);"></input>
    <br>
 How many Salads you want to order? <input type="number" id="Snum" value="0" onChange="getValue(this.value);"></input>
 <br>
    Price: <input id="price" readonly="readonly"></input>
</html>
```

Happy Coding...